# Init a UIView costume class with some data?

Tags: ios, swift

Right now my UIView class looks like this :

```
class CostumFlowViewCell: UIView {
    override init (frame : CGRect)
    {

        super.init(frame : frame)          

    }

    convenience init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }
```

I would like to be able to send it some array when I initialise it, so right now for example, I add it with :

```
let cell: CostumFlowViewCell= CostumFlowViewCell(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)
self.addSubView(cell)
```

How would I init it with some `NSArray` ? (inside the cell class , and when I add it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an initializer like this:

```
init(anArray: NSArray)
{
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    //do something with anArray
}
```

If you want the ability to init with an array and a frame, you can do so:

```
init(anArray: NSArray, frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)
    //do something with anArray
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add a convenience initializer to your class. See the code below:

```
convenience init(frame: CGRect, array:[AnyObject]) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        // good things to do...
    }
```